# Haskell Blaze HTML

Tags: haskell, happstack

been writing an application that consumes JSON data and then displays it using Happstack.

```
   helloBlaze :: ServerPart Response
   helloBlaze =
   ok $ toResponse $
   appTemplate "Hello, Blaze!"
            [H.meta ! A.name "keywords"
                    ! A.content "happstack, blaze, html"
            ]
            (do H.toHtml $ makeList $ getResponse)

   makeList xs = "<ul>" ++ (Items xs) ++ "</ul>"

   Items [] = ""
   Items (x:xs) = "<li>" ++ x ++ "</li>" ++ (Items xs)
```

The problem is when I run Happstack the response generated is the results but with html tags still showing. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Blaze all that well, but isn't the correct way to do this something more like

```
makeList xs = ul (mapM_ li xs)
```

That's how this works, isn't it?

(Also, don't use `Items` as a function name. It needs to start with a lowercase letter.)

Comment: Happstack_Server.hs:29:43:
    Couldn't match type `[Char]' with `Text.Blaze.Internal.MarkupM ()'
    Expected type: [H.Html]
      Actual type: [String]
    In the second argument of `($)', namely `processResponse'
    In the second argument of `($)', namely
      `makeList $ getResponse'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: H.toHtml $ makeList $ processResponse

Comment: getResponse returns a string :(

Comment: try `makeList xs = ul (mapM (li . H.toHtml) xs)`

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply, using the above code the error message I get                                                                                                                                  Couldn't match type `[()]' with `()'
                      Expected type: H.Html
                      Actual type: Text.Blaze.Internal.MarkupM [()]
                      In the return type of a call of `mapM'
                      In the first argument of `H.ul', namely
                      `(mapM (H.li . H.toHtml) xs)'
                     In the expression: H.ul (mapM (H.li . H.toHtml) xs)